# React shows stale data on player page

Tags: reactjs

I have a video player page that displays trailers.

**Question:**

> The first time when the video page loads, it works perfect! However,
>   if I select another video, I still see the stale data (even though the
>   props is passing in correct data). AKA I see Stale data. (But if I refresh the page, then it works fine)

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Videojs from './video.js';
import Loader from '../components/common/Loader';

const PlayerPage = props => {
  const { location } = props;
  const selectedMovieData = location.state && location.state.data;
  const link = selectedMovieData && selectedMovieData.downloadLink;

  const videoJsOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    preload: 'none',
    fluid: true,
    width: 1420,
    aspectRatio: '16:7',
    height: 300,
    techOrder: ['chromecast', 'html5'],
    controls: true,
    sources: [
      {
        src: link,
        type: 'video/mp4'
      }
    ],
  };

  const { loading } = useSelector(state => state.movieStore);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <VideoPlayStyle>
            <Videojs {...videoJsOptions} />
          </VideoPlayStyle>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlayerPage;
```

**Video.js component:**

```
// taken from https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/react.md
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/video.css';

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // instantiate video.js
    this.player = window.player = window.videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('VideoJS: onPlayerReady', this);
    });

    this.player.chromecast();
  }

  // destroy player on unmount
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose();
    }
  }

  // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
  // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
  // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
  render() {
    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)} className="video-js" id="play-video" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong. Any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm using React Hooks.

Comment: What's inside Videojs ?

Comment: Added it's a pretty basic videojs player component. if I refresh the page, it shows correct data. Should I use something like useEffect with cleanup or something in order to always render new component (without stale data?) @YupengLi

Comment: It could be because `this.player` is assigned a value only once (during componentDidMount). Are you sure this isn't an issue ?

Comment: I agree with Frosty619. componentDidMount is called only once. If prop changed, you should also handle componentDidUpdate